# How to use await, async and Task in asynchronous programming

Tags: c#, asynchronous

This is the first time I'm writing any asynchronous code. I am getting a compile error that says:

> Cannot implicitly convert type void to int

while the function is returning an `int`.

```
public class Function
{
    IAmazonS3 s3client = new AmazonS3Client(RegionEndpoint.USEast1);
    public async Task<int> ListS3ObjectsAsync(string bucketName, IAmazonS3 client)
    {
        ListObjectsRequest request = new ListObjectsRequest();
        request.BucketName = bucketName;

        ListObjectsResponse response = await client.ListObjectsAsync(request);
        do
        {
            if (response.IsTruncated)
                request.Marker = response.NextMarker;
            else
                request = null;

        } while (request != null);

        var len = response.S3Objects.Count;
        return len;
    }

    public void FunctionHandler(S3Event evnt, ILambdaContext context)
    {
        // Here I'm getting the compile error
        int x = ListS3ObjectsAsync(evnt.Records?[0].S3.Bucket.Name, s3client).Wait();
    }
}
```

Visual Studio screenshot:

[image: Visual Studio screenshot]

Comment: Instead of writing.Wait() after, write await before or Result after.

Comment: my suggestion is first write the non async version aka get that right, and then ask for the async as you are mixing thing anyway, it would be better to be able to write it at least correctly one way and then convert. conversion is quick. main issue here is in order to await an async function all its callers must be async., and wait() is the same as sync by worse...

Comment: This is not a question about the Visual Studio application, so I've removed that tag for you. Please be careful to read tag descriptions to ensure you don't misuse them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `ListS3ObjectsAsync` method returns a `Task<int>`, which is an asynchronous representation of getting an `int`, so in order to get the result, you either need to await the task like this:

`int x = await ListS3ObjectsAsync`

But that will require you to make the FunctionHandler async aswell.

Or you can call .Result on the task like this

```
var task = ListS3ObjectsAsync

int x = task.Result
```

Note that this is a blocking operation and mixing async and non async code is bad practise.

`.Wait` method only waits for the task to complete, but does not return the Result

Comment: basically what i said in the comment, but better thumbs up

Comment: @Selmir Aljic, thank you for your assistance, good tips. Second option worked.

Answer (score 2):

You [shouldn't block on `async` code](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html), so the best solution is to use `await` instead of `Wait`:

```
public void FunctionHandler(S3Event evnt, ILambdaContext context)
{
  int x = await ListS3ObjectsAsync(evnt.Records?[0].S3.Bucket.Name, s3client);
}
```

The compiler will then tell you the next part of the solution: `FunctionHandler` must be made `async` and its return type changed to `Task`, i.e.:

```
public async Task FunctionHandlerAsync(S3Event evnt, ILambdaContext context)
{
  int x = await ListS3ObjectsAsync(evnt.Records?[0].S3.Bucket.Name, s3client);
}
```

The ["growth" of `async` like this is normal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming).